# Given a Facebook access token, how can I get the permissions it has?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

One use case is the following.

I ask for a Facebook access token to new users with the `offline_access` permission and I store it for later use. If the user remove in his settings the `offline_access` permission the token becomes invalid.

I would like to be able to test (maybe using the graph API) if the token I have still have the permissions I asked for, without waiting the user to log out to try to make an API call.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just call the Permissions graph api method. You could parse the json response and look to see if "offline_access" exists or not.  The url format is: https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=...  You can access an example of it by going [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and clicking the permissions link there.  The

Comment: This is correct, however, be aware that as of 5/11 there is a bug preventing this from working: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/277040382385812

Answer (score 3):

You can also use their debug tool to check a token, useful for confirming the level a token has and what it has access to for debugging:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/